# c# find unused objects of specific class before garbage collection

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, garbage-collection

Hello and thank you very much for your help!

Does anybody have a good idea to find unreferenced objects of a specific class before garbage collection? (preferable as soon as possible)

In my case, I need to create a lot of small objects of a specific class for temporary use only. The problem is that I don’t know when the object is not needed anymore. I would like to collect the objects of that class which are not referenced any more (as soon as possible) before garbage collection so that I can recycle them and don’t need to create them new. I think that would make the code much faster.

Kind Regards,
David

Comment: What makes you think that your code would be much faster if you could recycle objects? I don't think I've seen such a case in C#.

Comment: Do these objects have a high initialization cost? If not, you're unlikely to realize any benefit.

Comment: @Gabe: I'm working on a game that will be significantly assisted by using object pools for certain objects. These objects live for a relatively short time, are usually very similar and are created very often. A pool fits my needs perfectly. Oh and I have done the performance measurement to know that a pool will help me out. :)

Answer (score 6):

First off, before you do this you should do extensive profiling to determine that you really, truly do have a performance problem caused by collection pressure. The garbage collector is highly tuned and works quite well most of the time; situations where you need to pool objects for performance reasons are rare.

I actually *am* in that scenario; we have determined through extensive testing that there are certain objects we use all the time on a temporary basis, ("builders" of other objects, essentially) and that the cost of collection pressure caused by re-allocating them frequently is measurable and high.

What we do is we have a pool class which maintains an array of "blank" objects. When you need a new object, the pool checks the array and returns an object that is in the array if we have one, nulling out the array entry. If we don't have one then it creates a new object. When the temporary user is done with the object, it passes it back to the pool, which "blanks" it and sticks it back in the array. (Growing the array if necessary.)

If a user forgets to put the object back into the pool, or cannot do so because an exception was thrown before the "back in the pool" call, who cares? All we've done in that case is perhaps slightly de-optimized a future allocation. The cost is that you need to remember to put the object back in the pool when you're done with it.

There's no way to "hook" the garbage collector to put stuff back in the pool automatically that I know of.

Comment: Do you use `IDisposable` to return the objects back to their pool?

Comment: @Gabe: Funnily enough we just had a discussion about that question on my team on Thursday. We decided that no, it was not appropriate to use IDisposable to move the objects back to the pool. First off, IDisposable should be used for *unmanaged* resources. Second, if an object gets reclaimed by the GC in an exceptional case then who cares? That case is exceptional and the program is probably about to terminate abnormally anyway. Third, if an object does not get moved back to the pool in a normal termination then we have assertions that note that fact, so we'll catch the bug.

Comment: I consider IDisposable to be useful for anything that requires deterministic lifetime management, of which unmanaged resources are only the most common. I think IObservable is the best example of a managed object that uses IDisposable. In this case, I would probably opt to implement IDisposable to enable the `using` pattern if it were appropriate.

Comment: @Eric: I agree with @Gabe, `IDisposable` is for anything that should have a deterministic lifetime. Finalizers are for unmanaged resources. (and of course, if you have a finalizer, you should have a `Dispose` method). But ofsource, you don't need `IDisposable`; you can always just write the `try-finally` yourself.

Comment: I am aware that I am in a minority in the belief that "using" and IDisposable are for polite early cleanup of scarce unmanaged resources. I find it unfortunate that we use it for, say, running finally blocks of an iterator. I'm also in a minority in my opinion that RAII is aterrible idea.

Comment: C# really needs a scope-based initialization/cleanup statement for things where using/IDisposable are inappropriate. I agree that overloading the IDisposable just to get scope-based behavior is bad but there are no other tools in the language to do so and enforcing coding patterns specific to certain object types on junior-level developers is like herding cats.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly control garbage collection, but you could create a manager class that is responsible for creating, holding the references and disposing of these objects.  As long as the manager class is in scope, its objects will not be garbage collected.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough, so I ask again: How can I identify unused (unreferenced) objects of a specific class, so that I know when it makes sense to recycle it? I don’t want to recycle an object which might be still in use (or is at least referenced).

Comment: You're thinking about it the wrong way.  This happens automatically.  If you don't want an object recycled keep the reference to it in scope and don't call `Dispose()`.  Read up on `using` statements, this might help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your help but I think we have a little misunderstanding. I would like to put all the unused (unreferenced) objects of a specific class in a special stack-list. When I need an object of that class again I just pop one out of the stack-list and use it again. If the stack-list is empty then I create a new object.

What are your thoughts about Weak References? Is possible with them to identify unused (unreferenced) objects?

Kind Regards,
David

Comment: What do these objects do?  It seems like you're trying to avoid the cost of instantiating new instances...maybe you're looking for the Singleton pattern?

Comment: Yes, that is correct! I’m trying to avoid the cost of instantiating. In my case I cannot use the singleton pattern because I need multiple instances (in some cases). I heard that the garbage collector has a list of unreferenced objects, is it possible to access that list? The optimum solution would be if an event could be raised every time one of the objects in question becomes unreferenced.

Comment: Not that I know of, but what you CAN do is: (1) Create a Singleton `ObjManager` class which contains a `Dictionary<Obj,bool>`, where Obj is the object and bool indicates if it is available.  It will manage the instances.  (2) Add an `event EventHandler Complete` on these `Obj` objects.  (3)  When the `ObjManager` creates a new `Obj`, it subscribes `Obj.Complete = (s,e)=>{ObjManager.Dictionary[(Obj)s] = true;`, and then adds the new `Obj` to the dictionary.  The boolean value indicates if the object is available.  (4) Make your API a call to `ObjManager.Instance.GetObj()`,

Comment: which checks the dictionary for an available instance.  If there is one then it returns it, or it creates a new one as I described.  (5) When you are done using `Obj`, invoke the `Completed(this,EventArgs.Empty), which will signify to `ObjManager` that the Obj is available again`